# How to use the excludePattern in camel for the remove headers?

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I tried to work with the camel's remove header which works for some and does not work for other patterns

It works for the below patterns

```
<removeHeaders pattern="*" />
<removeHeaders pattern="CamelFile*" />
```

It does not work for

```
<removeHeaders pattern="*File*" />
```

Is the above expected?

Also in the exclude pattern I observe that the wildcard patterns * is not recognised at all.

```
        <setHeader headerName="firstCustomHeader">
            <constant>firstCustomHeader</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="secondCustomHeader">
            <constant>secondCustomHeader</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="thirdCustomHeader">
            <constant>thirdCustomHeader</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="fourthCustomHeader">
            <constant>fourthCustomHeader</constant>
        </setHeader>

         <removeHeaders pattern="*" excludePattern="fourth*|third*" />
```

the above removes all the header but does excludes the excludePattern value

How do I achieve the relevant above mentioned pattern?

Camel Version 2.13.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes either use a regular expression or use a single `*` in the end as
wildcard. So `*File*` is not valid, as it has two `*`, and therefore Camel assumes its a regular expression.

So you should do a regular expression

```
pattern=".*File.*"
```

Where as if you have only one `*` its a shorthand for matching wildcards, but the `*` must be only once and at the end of the line, such as

```
pattern="File*"
```

The syntax is documented here

- http://camel.apache.org/intercept

Comment: Thanks Claus. Will the pattern in java dsl also support the regular expression ?

Comment: Yes the XML DSL and Java DSL has the same functionality

Answer (score 3):

1. You could accomplish the removeHeaders ****File**** using the following pattern: 
   `pattern="\w+File\w+"`
2. Similarly, your excludePattern can also be achieved using: 
   `excludePattern="fourth\w+|third\w+"`

These are basically regular expressions that can be tested [here](http://www.regexr.com/).